# Is elmnt.scrollIntoView usable with CSS class name or otherwise to scroll SharePoint calendar

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, scroll

I am trying to automate the scrolling of expanded SharePoint calendar so the current date/week is in view on a display with limited resolution.

I have no JS knowledge, but tried to use JS to scroll by referring to the today's date CSS class name. It doesn't seem to do the job.

What I tried is:

```
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-acal-today");
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
```

I reasoned that the script actually works with ID of an element. Unfortunately there is no id of the particular element in the SharePoint calendar, and can't put one there.
So I was hoping the CSS class name will do the trick, but to no avail.

Could you please advise how the scrolling of the today's date or current week into view in a browser window can be done through JS, provided that in Sharepoint calendar, the current date is:

```
<div class="ms-acal-today">
        <nobr>21</nobr>
    </div>
```

(if today is 21 of August 2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answered, but I managed to resolve the case with jQuery and here it is for anyone who might need it:

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
var $container = $("html,#s4-workspace");
var $scrollTo = $('.ms-acal-today');

$container.animate({scrollTop: $scrollTo.offset().top - $container.offset().top + $container.scrollTop(), scrollLeft: 0},600);
});
```

Of corse jQuery must be initiated in SharePoint first.
I did it by uploading jquery-3.4.1.min.js in the site assets and referring to it in web part.